# Convergence of a sequence of identically distributed, but dependent, random variables

Tags: analysis, probability-theory

Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space, and let $X_k: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of *identically distributed* random variables, with expectation
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} X_k = \mu \in [0,1],\quad \forall k.
\end{equation}
Define the sample average,
\begin{equation}
\bar{X}_n := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}X_k.
\end{equation}

> Can we say anything about the convergence of $\bar{X}_n$? Can we say $\bar{X}_n$ converges (to something, not necessarily $\mu$) as $n \to \infty$? What can go wrong?

Of course, if the $X_k$'s are, in addition, *independent*, then the Strong Law of Large Numbers (SLLN) says the sample average converges to $\mu$,
\begin{equation}
\bar{X}_n \to \mu,\quad \mathbb{P}-\text{a.s.}
\end{equation}
But I am curious about dropping the independence criterion. A simple counterexample removing independence for the SLLN would be to take $X_k = X$ for all $k$, for some $X$ with $\mathbb{E} X = \mu$. But in this case we still have (trivially) convergence of $\bar{X}_n$.

Comment: Was my answer below helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega = \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ with the Borel sigma-algebra and $\mathbb{P}$ be the $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$ product measure. Let $X(\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots)$ be $0$ if $\omega_1 = 0$ and $1$ if $\omega_1 = 1$. Let $Y(\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots)$ be $1$ if $\omega_1 = 0$ and $0$ if $\omega_1 = 1$. Let

$X_1 = X$

$X_2,X_3 = Y$

$X_4,X_5,X_6,X_7 = X$

$X_8,\dots,X_{15} = Y$.

Etc. The point is that for any $\omega$, the sums $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} Y_n(\omega)$ won't converge for any $\omega$.